# Have capsule-free taxi spacecraft ever been seriously considered for non-emergency use?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, design-alternative, space-tug

Capsules are heavy, but necessary.
Or at least, they are necessary for launch, landing, and stays in space lasting more than an hour or two.

But it is possible to imagine situations where cosmonauts would want to move quickly from one location to another, with a high relative velocity, where both the origin and the destinations have shelters. An example would be boarding an interplanetary cycler as it flies by.

For a "taxi" spacecraft, mass could be saved by eliminating the crew capsule. "The crew dresses up in EVA suits and grabs on to the rocker".

Understandably, no mission profiles to date have been suitable for such spacecraft. Almost all manned traffic is up and down to LEO, which requires a capsule. The exception would be Apollo, but there were no shelter infrastructure for it to take advantage of, instead minimizing risk by flying everything in a single stack.

The [Lunar Escape System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_escape_systems) was such a capsule-free proposal, but it was only considered for emergency use.

**Has such a capsule-free spacecraft ever been seriously proposed for regular use?**

Comment: What about the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Maneuvering_Unit)? Would that satisfy your criteria? (And subsequently, SAFER?)

Comment: @Polygnome Not really, since they are neither high impulse, nor intended to reach some other destination. But good point.

Comment: I have to wonder just how ridiculous a chemical-power MMU would be.

Comment: Two notes: first, can't EVAs last a lot longer than 2 hours? Second, how high is high relative velocity? Most descriptions of these vehicles I've seen (pressurized or no) have been fairly low delta-V (hundreds) and intended more to cover moderate distance than to handle relative velocity. Of course you do see insanity in science fiction like Alistair Reynolds' nuclear thermal rocket taxi.

Comment: About 20 years ago, a design for an open style Lunar transport platform was being proposed by one of the bigs for crew travel across the Moon's surface. I can remember [John Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Young_(astronaut)) railing against the concept - he did not like the idea of a space suit being the only thing between a crew member and an [MMOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_debris) hit. Trouble was, old John was usually right...

Comment: I'm trying to understand the intended usage for such a vehicle.  You need crew in two different orbits.  Why are you routinely transferring crew between these two orbits, instead of each orbit having its own dedicated crew for whatever tasks they are to perform?

Comment: @DrSheldon things like manned missions to the Moon or Mars require moving crew between orbits.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys: Okay, I didn't realize you were thinking of such a long-duration flight.  Without a crew compartment?  Yikes.

Comment: @DrSheldon No, the long-duration part is just coasting, safely inside a shelter (I hope!). This is more for the few minutes of acceleration required at the beginning and end of such coasting.

Comment: This system could have been used during the [Soyuz T-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_T-15) mission, which visited both Mir and Salyut 7

Comment: Actually, you probably don't even need a capsule to launch to LEO. I [asked a similar question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54159/could-one-survive-a-ride-into-orbit-outside-a-rocket) here a while ago; it is potentially survivable to simply duct tape yourself to a rocket. *Maybe* a special, more sturdy suit would be nice that shields the passenger better from sound and heat. I suppose you want to be sideways to avoid fainting from the blood assembling in your <strike>balls</strike>feet. All told, it's probably more a desperate  SevenEves idea but still.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is pretty much a [space tug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tug).  Examining that web page, those which were proposed during the Apollo era had a proper crew compartment, and during the Shuttle era and later were uncrewed.  So the answer appears to be "no".